# Finding the minimum

Tags: functions

I am trying to find the minimum R and its corresponding k, but for some reason (which I am not able to figure it out) I am getting an error that the function value is not a real number at k=1.

```
f11 = z^4 - 2*z^3 + z^2; 
f21 = ((27*z^4)/5)*(z^2 - 1)^4; 
f1 = Sin[k*x]*f11; 
f2 = (-((k*f11)/(k^2*f21 - D[f21, {z, 2}])))*Cos[k*x]*f21; 
I1 = D[f1, {x, 4}] + 2*D[f1, {x, 2}, {z, 2}] + D[f1, {z, 4}]
I2 = D[f2, {x, 1}]
R = I1/I2
FindMinimum[R, k]
```

Please tell me how do I get rid of this error?

Comment: `FindMinimum` is a *numerical* function. It won't find a symbolic minimum. Thus, if you're going to use it, you need to specify numeric values for `x` and `z`.

Comment: What constraints, if any, exist for `k` or `R`?

Comment: `k` and `R` are both positive

Comment: Its not an errror, its an impossible task

Comment: @Math_student After simplification `R` only depends on `k,z`! Are you looking for the global minimum or for the z-dependant minimum?

Comment: UlrichNeumann (@ does not work.): The global minimum is always `-Infinity` up to `Minimize[{I1/I2 // Simplify, k > 0}, {k, z}]` which results in "Minimize::natt: The minimum is not attained at any point satisfying the given constraints." and `{-\[Infinity], {k -> Indeterminate, z -> Indeterminate}}`. Therefore, you open an opened door.

Answer (score 0):

Its not an errror, its an impossible task. An extremum is located at a zero of the numerator of the derivative wrt. k.

```
     Reduce[0 == D[R, k] // ExpandAll // Together // Numerator]



(-1 + z) z (1 + z) !=  0 && (k == -\[Sqrt]Root[  144 - 1152 z^2 + 
     1584 z^4 + (-8 z^2 + 24 z^3 + 34 z^4 - 120 z^5 + 4 z^6 + 
        144 z^7 - 78 z^8) #1^2 + (z^4 - 2 z^5 - z^6 + 4 z^7 - 
        z^8 - 2 z^9 + z^10) #1^3 &, 1] ||
 k == \[Sqrt]Root[ 144 - 1152 z^2 +  1584 z^4 + 
       (-8 z^2 + 24 z^3 + 34 z^4 - 120 z^5 + 4 z^6 +  144 z^7 - 78 z^8) #1^2 + 
        (z^4 - 2 z^5 - z^6 + 4 z^7 - z^8 - 2 z^9 + z^10) #1^3 &, 1] ||
   k == -\[Sqrt]Root[  144 - 1152 z^2 + 
     1584 z^4 + (-8 z^2 + 24 z^3 + 34 z^4 - 120 z^5 + 4 z^6 + 
        144 z^7 - 78 z^8) #1^2 + (z^4 - 2 z^5 - z^6 + 4 z^7 - 
        z^8 - 2 z^9 + z^10) #1^3 &, 2] ||
  k == \[Sqrt]Root[  144 - 1152 z^2 +  1584 z^4 + 
           (-8 z^2 + 24 z^3 + 34 z^4 - 120 z^5 + 4 z^6 + 
       144 z^7 - 78 z^8) #1^2 + (z^4 - 2 z^5 - z^6 + 4 z^7 - 
       z^8 - 2 z^9 + z^10) #1^3 &, 2] || 
  k == -\[Sqrt]Root[144 - 1152 z^2 + 
     1584 z^4 + (-8 z^2 + 24 z^3 + 34 z^4 - 120 z^5 + 4 z^6 + 
        144 z^7 - 78 z^8) #1^2 + (z^4 - 2 z^5 - z^6 + 4 z^7 - 
        z^8 - 2 z^9 + z^10) #1^3 &, 3] || 
  k == \[Sqrt]Root[   144 - 1152 z^2 + 
    1584 z^4 + (-8 z^2 + 24 z^3 + 34 z^4 - 120 z^5 + 4 z^6 + 
       144 z^7 - 78 z^8) #1^2 + (z^4 - 2 z^5 - z^6 + 4 z^7 - 
       z^8 - 2 z^9 + z^10) #1^3 &, 3]) && k != 0
```

For real z

```
   Reduce[0 == D[R, k] // ExpandAll // Together // Numerator, Reals]
```

yields an even longer list.

Answer (score 0):

The following works in 13.3.1 on Windows 10.

```
f11 = z^4 - 2*z^3 + z^2;f21 = ((27*z^4)/5)*(z^2 - 1)^4;f1 = Sin[k*x]*f11;
f2 = (-((k*f11)/(k^2*f21 - D[f21, {z, 2}])))*Cos[k*x]*f21;
I1 = D[f1, {x, 4}] + 2*D[f1, {x, 2}, {z, 2}] + D[f1, {z, 4}];
I2 = D[f2, {x, 1}];R = I1/I2;
Minimize[{R, k > 0}, k]
```

> Size in memory:0.5 MB

Addition.

```
Minimize[{R /. {x -> 1, z -> 1/2}, k > 0}, k] // ToRadicals
```

> `{(3 (80 +  1/3 (-88 + (1184768 - 13824 Sqrt[4915])^(1/3) +  8 (2314 + 27 Sqrt[4915])^(1/3))) (384 +  32/9 (-88 + (1184768 - 13824 Sqrt[4915])^(1/3) +  8 (2314 + 27 Sqrt[4915])^(1/3)) +  1/81 (-88 + (1184768 - 13824 Sqrt[4915])^(1/3) +  8 (2314 + 27 Sqrt[4915])^(1/3))^2))/(-88 + (1184768 -  13824 Sqrt[4915])^(1/3) + 8 (2314 + 27 Sqrt[4915])^(1/3)), {k -> 1/3 Sqrt[-88 + (1184768 - 13824 Sqrt[4915])^(1/3) +  8 (2314 + 27 Sqrt[4915])^(1/3)]}}`

```
N[%]
```

> `{2934.12, {k -> 3.35176}}`

Comment: The result of `Minimize[{Max[R, 0], k > 0}, k] // PiecewiseExpand` is not so long, but the one uses roots of  polynomials of degree 14.

Answer (score 0):

```
f11 = z^4 - 2*z^3 + z^2; 
f21 = ((27*z^4)/5)*(z^2 - 1)^4; 
f1 = Sin[k*x]*f11; 
f2 = (-((k*f11)/(k^2*f21 - D[f21, {z, 2}])))*Cos[k*x]*f21; 
I1 = D[f1, {x, 4}] + 2*D[f1, {x, 2}, {z, 2}] + D[f1, {z, 4}];
I2 = D[f2, {x, 1}];
R = I1/I2 //Simplify
```

$\frac{\left(k^2 z^6-2 \left(k^2+66\right)
   z^4+\left(k^2+96\right) z^2-12\right) \left(k^4 (z-1)^2 z^2-4
   k^2 \left(6 z^2-6 z+1\right)+24\right)}{k^2 (z-1)^4 z^4
   (z+1)^2}$

`R`only depends on `z,k` and gets singulaer for `z={-1,0,1}`,
no minimum exists!

Comment: Don't hurry with conclusions. For some parameters the minimum exists. For example, the result of `Minimize[{I1/I2 /. {x -> 1, z -> 1/2}, k > 0}, k]` is identical to the result of `Minimize[{Simplify[I1/I2] /. {x -> 1, z -> 1/2}, k > 0}, k]`. Also the result of `Minimize[{Simplify[I1/I2], k > 0}, k]` takes in memory 0.5 MB too.

Comment: @user64494 If you 're looking for a z-dependent minimum you're right. But a global finite minimum doesn't exist.

Comment: Sorry, " a global finite minimum " is not asked in the question..

Comment: @user64494 The question is unclear. I asked QP for clarification.

Comment: UlrichNeumann (@ does not work.): The global minimum is always `-Infinity` up to `Minimize[{I1/I2 // Simplify, k > 0}, {k, z}]` which results in "Minimize::natt: The minimum is not attained at any point satisfying the given constraints." and `{-\[Infinity], {k -> Indeterminate, z -> Indeterminate}}`. Therefore, you open an opened door.